# Stacked areachart with percents values on the y axis using Charts.js and Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js, ng2-charts

I'am using Angular 8 and ng2-charts package to create a stacked areachart. I want to create a chart [like this](https://www.anychart.com/chartopedia/chart-type/percent-stacked-splinearea-chart/). I tried to use min and max values to create Y axis from 0% to 100%, but it works incorrect with different data (if the sum of data for each label is greater than 100, then the graph is out of bounds). I also want to display them stacked on top of one another, but don't know how to achieve this.

I also attach [my code on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-444qxy), where I tried to wrote this.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated answer:**

I don't know anything about typescript or angular. That's why I wrote my program in plain Javascript.

Took me quite some time, updating the legend is not that easy in `chart.js`...

I know it's quite complexe and may not be an optimal solution. Please feel free to ask me about the code or tell me possible improvements.

Complete code with live-preview: https://jsbin.com/detiqucime/6/edit?js,output

Complete code:

```
let canvas = document.getElementById("chart");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

const dataLabels = [
  'First', 
  'Second', 
  'Third'
]

const colors = {
  'First': '#bad96b',
  'Second': '#8ad0f9',
  'Third': '#ffda78'
}

let data = [
  [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
  [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90],
  [22, 44, 23, 69, 82, 47, 50]
]

// hiddenArray (array with 'true' or 'null' (hidden or not) to know which datasets are hidden, those get not calculated)
let hiddenArray = []
// Initiate hiddenArray: nothing hidden at start
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  hiddenArray.push(null)
}

// New data array we use for the chart
let percentageData = []

calcPercentages(hiddenArray)

function calcPercentages(hiddenArray) {
  percentageData = []

  // Fill percentageData with empty arrays for same structure like data
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    percentageData.push([])
  }

  for (let innerKey in data[0]) {
    // Get the sum of each data
    let sum = 0
    for (let outerKey in data) {
      if (hiddenArray[outerKey]) {
        continue;
      }
      sum = sum + data[outerKey][innerKey]
    }

    // Calculate the new percentageData
    for (let outerKey in data) {
      if (hiddenArray[outerKey]) {
        percentageData[outerKey][innerKey] = 0
      } else {
        percentageData[outerKey][innerKey] = (data[outerKey][innerKey]/sum)*100
      }
    }
  }
}

let chartData = {
  labels: ['2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012'],
  datasets: []
}

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  let newDataset = {}
  newDataset.label = dataLabels[i]
  newDataset.backgroundColor = colors[dataLabels[i]]
  newDataset.data = percentageData[i]
  chartData.datasets.push(newDataset)
}

let options = {
  responsive: true,
  legend: {
    //reverse: true,
    onClick: function(e, legendItem) {
      let index = legendItem.datasetIndex;
      let ci = this.chart;      
      let meta = ci.getDatasetMeta(index);

      // Change 'hidden'-property
      meta.hidden = meta.hidden === null ? !ci.data.datasets[index].hidden : null;      

      // Get hiddenArray
      let hiddenArray = []

      ci.data.datasets.forEach(function(e, i) {
        let meta = ci.getDatasetMeta(i);
        hiddenArray.push(meta.hidden)
      });

      // Update percentageData
      calcPercentages(hiddenArray)

      for (let i = 0; i < percentageData.length; i++) {
        chartData.datasets[i].data = percentageData[i]
      }

      // Rerender the chart
      ci.update();
    }
  },
  scales: {
    yAxes: [{
      stacked: true,
      ticks: {
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        callback: function(value) {
          return value + '%'
        }
      }
    }],
  },
  tooltips: {
    callbacks: {
      label: function(tooltipItem){
        return data[tooltipItem.datasetIndex][tooltipItem.index]
      }
    }
  }
}

let myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: chartData,
  options: options,
});
```

Comment: This is almost what I wanted, but I will still need to make the display of the point value equal to the non-percentage value. Also the problem is that if you remove the display of any label, the chart on the level below is not redrawn with 100% maximum value. I assume this requires a callback to redraw the chart with new values.

Comment: @Syncmaxim I updated my post. Feel free to ask me about it.

Comment: In my solution it's easy to add an additional dataset. Note that the animation is not 100% correct because of the wrong animation order. You can find an solution for that [on GitHub](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/5181#issuecomment-360328471) I didn't add that in my code.

Comment: _Took me quite some time, updating the legend is not that easy in chart.js..._ I'm fully agree with you. 
And this is what I expected to get. I will try to implement it using angular and then I will tell you about the results. I also will update my question with working angular code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please find the updated code snippet of the component below. Updated the answer accordingly in the stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-444qxy)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ChartDataSets, ChartOptions } from 'chartjs';
import { Color, Label } from 'ng2-charts';
import 'chartjs-plugin-zoom';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent {
  lineChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [];
  lineChartLabels: Label[] = [];

  lineChartOptions: ChartOptions = {
    legend: {
      reverse: true
    },
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{}],
      xAxes:[{}]
    },
    pan: {
      enabled: true,
      mode: 'x',
    },
    zoom: {
      enabled: true,
      mode: 'x',
      speed: 1.5
    },
  };

  lineChartColors: Color[] = [];

  lineChartLegend = true;
  lineChartPlugins = [];
  lineChartType = 'line';

  ngOnInit() {
    this.lineChartData = [
    { data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40], label: 'First'},
    { data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 110, 27, 90], label: 'Second'},
    { data: [22, 44, 23, 69, 82, 47, 50], label: 'Third'}
    ];

    this.lineChartLabels = ['2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012'];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is to find maximum y value of your graph and then calculate each other value as a percentage of this found maximum one.

For example like this:

```
let sumOfData = [];
this.lineChartData.forEach((elem) => elem.data.forEach((value, index) => {
    if(!sumOfData[index]) {
      sumOfData[index] = value;
    } else {
      sumOfData[index] += value;
    }
}));
this.maxChartValue = Math.max(...sumOfData);
```

Working [example on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jg6zme)

Of course any other arbitrary number to calculate percents for the graph may be used. If it is greater, than a maximum one, then it will look more similar to the example from anychart.com that you linked to. 
 
**In any case you need some number in order to determine percent of it. 

Just some values in array won't do.**

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a solution, but just a way to find the maximum value. In any case, the resulting value must still be displayed correctly.